# Yosemite Finder Sync simple example

Tags: objective-c, osx-yosemite, finder

I am trying to create a simple (ie. Hello World) example of Yosemite's [Finder Sync](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Finder.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH15-SW1).

That link has a tutorial, but does anyone know where the source is? Or if they have their own barebones example? Something that can register when a folder is being viewed and how to create a context menu

Comment: Welcome to a world of pain ... https://devforums.apple.com/thread/243496?tstart=0 https://devforums.apple.com/thread/241727?tstart=50 https://devforums.apple.com/thread/240363?tstart=50

Comment: Did you get how to use FinderSync? I want to  have my custom image on folder.

Answer (score 10):

A Hello World example is available as a template in Xcode.  From an existing application project, pick File->New->Target, choose Application Extensions, pick the Finder Sync Extension, give it a name and hit Finish.  Then take a look at the FinderSync.m file added in your new target, it has the basics such as badging a file and providing a context menu and toolbar.

Comment: But how it works? I tried compiling, building running, nothing happens.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya You have to select the extension scheme and run it. Then you'll have to chose which application you want the extension to run in. Choose Finder.

Answer (score 4):

Checkout [liferay-nativity](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-nativity)
It provides pretty good examples of how to handle Finder Sync Extensions.
Another open source project is [seafile](https://github.com/haiwen/seafile-client/blob/7d73ba314aedbd7a05428de649ce2a1cce37f676/fsplugin/FinderSync.mm).